# Pure python cross-platform font renderer?

Tags: python, fonts

I'm looking for a pure Python font renderer.  I don't need it to render to anything special, I just need the pixel colors/alpha. I'm using PIL right now, but I am not sure if it needs to hook into any system libraries that may not be installed.

Pyglet manages this, somehow, but I wasn't able to determine the relevant code. I am working on a gui for pyglet, so if I could use this, that would probably be even better.

Comment: By "pure Python", you mean it is not allowed to have any parts coded in C?

Comment: PIL uses freetype to load ttf/otf, and libpng/libjpg depending on your output format.

Comment: Font rendering is not something you want to do in Python; it's a complex computational task.  That's what native modules are *for*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyglet uses [FreeType](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/) where available. I'd stick with that, even though it's not pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

ReportLab can render to pixmaps:

http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/2.4/graphics.html#module-reportlab.graphics.renderPM

probably a bit heavyweight for your needs though.